# Merging numbers to form a big number

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

If I have an int array with elements {1,2,3,4}

and I do not want to add the ints inside it but instead I want to have an int variable that holds the first 3 digits of the array for it to be int x = 123; and 123 being the first 3 elements{1,2,3} of the array, any ideas?

Basically instead of having 1 2 3 as separate digits in 3 separate indexes of the array I'd like to have 1 index OR variable that will be 123 as an actual 3 digit number.

Comment: create a variable initialized to zero and start adding numbers from the end. Before you add `n`th number, multiply it by 10^`(n - 1)`. No code for you, you should try it yourself, since you now know the algorithm

Comment: And there is an even simpler way to do it than that. Good starting place, though.

Comment: Thanks, managed to reach somewhere here:

   int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int x = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        x = x*10;
        x = x+arr[i];
    }
    cout << x;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approch. First of all assign the first digit of array (stored at array[0]) to the variable x. Then multiply it with 10 and then add the next digit of array into it, and do it one more time to insert first three digits into variable x.

Here is the code and hope it helps

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4}, x = 0, i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        x = (x * 10) + array[i];
    }
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want this code in C++ then :- Replace "#include<stdio.h>" by "#include<iostream.h>" and "printf("%d",x);" by "cout<<x;".

Comment: Never `void main`!  `int main`!

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is long since obsolete.  You mean `<iostream>`.

Comment: both can be used (iostream.h & iostream) and I had used void main because here its not a module of any other program so it doesn't need to return any value, though its a good programming habit to use int main instead.

Comment: @MaheshSuthar `iostream.h` cannot be used. It's not standard. `void main` cannot be used. It's not standard. The fact that some compilers accept them on some settings for backward compatibility is utterly irrelevant. It's not standard. They cannot be used in standard C++.